# http://localhost/ not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apache-http-server, php, html

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu (10.04.1) plus LAMP (via sudo tasksel install lamp-server) and everything is working fine, until I need to work on localhost when I do not have an internet connection. For example, as soon as I unplug the ethernet cable from the NIC, localhost and 127.0.0.1 stop working. The message I get from the browser is:

This web page is not available.

Then, as soon as I plug the ethernet cable into the laptop again, everything is back to normal again. I need to work on localhost sometimes when I do not have access to the internet.

Any idea how to fix this problem? I had this problem before, but can't remember when I did to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost does not work with chromium.

Comment: It was a bug in 1 of the versions of chromium, which has now been resolved.